# Hamilton function of a point charge

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, quantum-electrodynamics, radiation

In Fermi’s 1932 paper, Quantum theory of radiation, he wrote a “Hamilton function of a point charge in radiation field”
[image]

I am not able to get how to derive this equation. I have also looked up at Jackson’s Electrodynamics book, but unable to do so. Please help.

From Landau's "Field Theory" book, there's an expression, which is similar but not exact. It goes:

$$-\left\{\left(\frac{H-e \mathbf{\phi}}{c}\right)^2-\left(\mathbf{P}-\frac{e}{c} \mathbf{A} \right)^2\right\}+mc^2=0$$
Are they equivalent? Or Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two are completely equivalent except for an irrelevant additive constant. Note that what Fermi denotes by $W_a$, $\mathbf U$ and $V$ is $\mathcal H$, $\mathbf A$ and $\phi$ in Landau, resp.

With this in mind, rearrange Fermi's Eq. (13) and multiply both sides by $2m$
$$\left [\left( mc+\frac{W_a-eV}{c} \right)^2-\left( \mathbf p-\frac{e}{c}\mathbf U \right)^2 \right]=m^2c^2 \tag{1}$$
then multiply again by $c^2$
$$\left( mc^2+W_a-eV \right)^2-c^2\left( \mathbf p-\frac{e}{c}\mathbf U \right)^2 =m^2c^4$$
This is equivalent to
$$W_a  = \sqrt{c^2\left( \mathbf p-\frac{e}{c}\mathbf U \right)^2 +m^2c^4}+eV -mc^2\tag{2}$$

Now rearrange Landau's formula Eq. 16.7 in "THE CLASSICAL THEORY OF FIELDS", page 46:
$$\left( \frac{\mathcal H -e\phi}{c} \right)^2=\left( \mathbf p-\frac{e}{c}\mathbf A \right)^2 +m^2c^2$$
or Eq.16.8
$$\mathcal H  =\sqrt{c^2\left( \mathbf p-\frac{e}{c}\mathbf A \right)^2 +m^2c^4}+e\phi\tag{3}$$

Equations (2) and (3) differ in the absolute constant $mc^2$.

Comment: But why is it irrelevant and appears in the equation?

Comment: $W_a$ is the total energy without the rest energy $mc^2$, in other words it is the speed dependent variable kinetic term, so to speak, with both $m=$ and $c$ are absolute constants.

Comment: Could you please expand on this? Thanks for your help. I’ll add the bounty.

Comment: $E=\sqrt{(mc^2)^2+(pc)^2}=mc^2\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}}$,then $W=E-mc^2=mc^2\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}}-mc^2 =  mc^2(1+\frac{1}{2}\frac{v^2}{c^2}+\frac{3}{8}\frac{v^4}{c^4}+\frac{5}{16}\frac{v^6}{c^6}+...)-mc^2= \frac{1}{2}m v^2 (1+\frac{3}{4}\frac{v^2}{c^2}+\frac{5}{8}\frac{v^4}{c^4}+...)$